# Appending parameters to POST form url

Tags: url, forms, parameters

I am currently trying to code a link so I do not need to enter the values everything I need to check for my registered mails.

Example here is

http://singpost.com/ra/ra_article_status.asp where u need to type RR624613237SG into the box to get the information

```
            <INPUT type=submit class=buttons name=go value="Track" onClick="javascript:check_input();">
```

I have tried linking as

urlontop?Track=RR624613237SG

and other methods but failed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can only encode GET values in the url, and not POST parameters.

Comment: jbochi is right! POST is for security. GET is so you can bookmark and return later.